# VSCode won't debug with scanf

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, scanf, vscode-debugger

I have this problem in Visual Studio Code (for Win10), with Code Runner extention (run in terminal is checked). I wrote a very simple program to test it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    printf("Print:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

and found out that whenever and wherever I put a `scanf()` function in my program it just stops working in debugging mode. The .exe program just works fine, but if I try to debug it nothing happens. If I hit the "pause" button in the debugger, the first printf shows up together with an error message: "Stopping due to fatal error: AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (GDB exited unexpectedly.)".

I also tried adding `fflush(stdout);` after the first `printf()` but nothing changes, that was to be expected as it works fine if I comment out the `scanf()`. I literally have no other idea of what is worth trying at this point, hoping to find a solution here.

Comment: "GDB exited unexpectedly" This probably means you have a faulty/buggy version of gdb installed. You may want ty try and use gdb on the command line rather than from inside VS, and see if the error persists.

Comment: Aside: Better to test return value of `scanf()` before printing.  Example: `if (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) printf("%d", x);`

Comment: change `printf("%d", x);` to `printf("%d\n", x);`